# Artifactory not sourcing go module major versions correctly

Tags: go, artifactory, go-modules

I am releasing a major version update to a go module but Artifactory will not pull the version when incremented by go module requirements.

There post [here](https://go.dev/blog/v2-go-modules) and [here](https://jfrog.com/blog/find-the-path-to-go-module-major-versions-with-gocenter/), say to create a `v2/` directory and add `v2` to the module path, which I have done. Locally, go mod is very happy and I can import both from the github tags.

However artifactory does not recognize the tag. Its a github  repo with multiple packages. The tag structure I have tested has gone as follows.

- `product/v2.0.0` - Artifactory will not recognize the tag nor
  cache the path. It does not find the mod url
- `product/v2/v2.0.0` -
  Artifactory finds it, but does not import the mod file, so useless.

Has anyone run into this before? Artifactory supports go modules so I would imagine major releases would be supported too.

Comment: Artifactory knows to handle it very well. A link to your GitHub project can be very helpful. If it is private, then try to reproduce it with a public project.